# changing the base pointer of a process

Tags: c#, c++, windows, memory

I have a more theoretical question with pointers and memory allocation.
Lets say for example I have a process running and it has allocated 2 bytes from 0x01 to 0x03.
If I want to read from that memory I'll probably use ReadProcessMemory.
But what pointer am I specifically supposed to give?
 Is it a relative or an absolute pointer?
Lets say this pointer is relative, so I call ReadProcessMemory with a pointer to 0x00.
But how does Windows know where the process memory begins and where it ends?
Doesn't Windows have to save the address of the point where memory belongs to (or was allocatred by) a process? 
 But where does Windows save that information and how does it know where it saved the information? 
 I heard of something called a 'base pointer'. I suppose it is what I'm looking for. 
 The place where the memory belongs to a process. 
OK, but now let's say I want to copy the memory of a process somewhere (HDD maybe?) to clean up my memory for a little while. Then I want to put memory back where it was before, but I cant tell windows 'allocate 2048 bytes from 0x00c to 0x80c'.
 I have to say 'allocate 2048 bytes somewhere' and then Windows tells me where that 'somewhere' is. 
But if I relaunch my app again I would have to tell it 'hello process, your whole memory is not at 0x01 anymore, its now at 0x0c'. 
 Is there any way of acomplshing this? Maybe c# or c++ or just an opinion (again it is a **theoretical** question. Not about is it good or bad, just is it possible?).

Comment: There are like 42 questions here, all jumbled up.  Are you ultimately trying to figure out how to scan all the memory in a system?

Comment: Why are you trying to deal with memory in Windows in this way?  I think it would be far more productive if you explained what it is you are trying to do.  Windows memory management is a very complex topic and to explain it in the context of your question(s) would be difficult at best.

Comment: No, not at all. I want to temporarily free a process' memory, and then at some point put it back in the place it was before. No memory scans at all.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "base pointer", at least in Win32 land. (POSIX has something similar IIRC)

Comment: Man, this is like asking how does the universe exists, or seems to exist. Let the OS-making guys bother with this and get some sleep.

Comment: I'm not tired at all after 8 energy drinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OK, but now let's say I want to copy the memory of a process somewhere (HDD maybe?) to clean up my memory for a little while. Then I want to put memory back where it was before, but I cant tell windows 'allocate 2048 bytes from 0x00c to 0x80c'.

Simply allocate memory yourself. Windows is a virtual memory system. If it cannot fit things into physical memory, then it will simply page the memory back to disk. There's no need for any work on your part to cause this to happen.

EDIT: In more response to the comment, if you want to actually **deallocate** the memory used by the other process, you are completely out of luck. There's no way for you to reliably determine how the target process is using that memory, and you would probably cause immediate termination of the target process due to access violation.

Moreover, all memory allocation on Windows NT and derivatives goes down to the VirtualAlloc functions, which can only be used within the context of the calling process -- you cannot force the other process to do it for you.

I suppose you could write yourself a kernel driver which would write random garbage into the memory manager that would make it do what you want, but at the bare minimum you would cause failure of the target process, and most likely failure of the entire system.

But again, your question doesn't fundamentally make sense because Windows **already makes decisions** like this with respect to moving process' memory out to disk. Windows is a [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) system, and a particular memory location only makes sense in the context of an existing process.

Comment: But that is exactly what I want to do. I 'only' want to **temporarily** free the memory another process allocated. Then at some point later, I want to put it back, but then I cant allocate _exactly_ the same place, so I have to change the point where the process thinks his memory is.

Comment: @thebigone: Windows already does that for you, and it automatically chooses pieces of memory that aren't commonly being used when possible. Keep in mind that the memory addresses stored in the process aren't valid anywhere but that process. Even if another process has filled it's virtual address space, you could still be using all of the "main memory" on the system.

Comment: what do you mean with "main memory"?

Comment: @thebigone: Physical RAM. Memory addresses as seen by the process have absolutely **nothing** to do with those memory locations in physical memory. (Indeed, those addresses may point to somewhere on disk, which wouldn't be in physical memory alt all!)

Comment: Yes if the process was actually running it would cause a failure, but what if I call SuspendThread on all of the process' threads? Wouldn't it be possible to deallocate its memory and then, before calling ResumeThread putting it all back where it was at the beginning?

Comment: @thebigone: 1. No. You can't call `VirtualFree` or `VirtualAlloc` for another process. 2. Even if you could, there's no reason you would ever **want** to.

Comment: I think you still don't understand what I wanna do. Yesterday I started writing a program for the following purpose: Let's say youre running a big task which consumes lots of memory, like unzipping a huge zip. And then a friend of you wants to see your new video game or something like that. You have 2 options: 1. abort the unzipping, then you'll have to do it again. or 2) Showing that game but it will not work properly because of memory consumption by unzipping process. My program is going to freeze the unzipping. Understood?

Comment: @thebigone: But that's not true. If you suspend the zipping process, Windows will page out it's memory automatically if it needs to. Your game should not be affected (at least not as a result of memory consumption)

Comment: ok, so its perfectly fine to just suspend it? The memory consumtion of 700MB by the (un)zipping process is not affecting my game/video or something like that? Wow, but why is it so slow then? When I kill (abort) the unzipping it runs fine.

Comment: @thebigone: I don't know. How are you suspending the target process?

Comment: @thebigone: Not sure then. Whatever it is, it's not memory related. Perhaps disk I/O? Perhaps the process isn't well and truly suspended? Perhaps it's just the startup of the game, and the zipping program hasn't yet been paged to disk? (You could do what the "Memory freers" do (i.e. RAMIdle, Cacheman) and just allocate a large chunk of memory for yourself, forcing the offending process to be paged)

Comment: @Bill ONeal, but you can call VirtualAllocEx and VirtualFreeEx to allocate and free memory in a different process.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Your statement about VirtualAlloc is completely wrong. In NT page allocations come down to NtAllocateVirtualMemory, which has ProcessHandle as its first parameter. VirtualAlloc(Ex) is just a wrapper around this function.

Comment: @shf301: Interesting. Though it still doesn't solve the OP's problem. @wj32: `NtAllocateVirtualMemory` is an undocumented internal function. And below `NtAllocateVirtualMemory` you're going to have other kernel mode processes that are involved. That doesn't mean you should be calling them from user mode code. All of the *supported* memory allocation routines are built on top of `VirtualAlloc` and friends.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Whatever you stated about "undocumented", "internal" and "kernel-mode" is irrelevant. NtAllocateVirtualMemory is a system call, and page allocations are achieved through this function. This function allows you to allocate memory within any process. Is this clear enough?

Comment: Wow, so I really could do what I was going to do before? Nice. I could call VirtualAllocEx and VirtualFreeEx whith a process handle as parameter and free another process' memory. Then I could allocate it again. But would it be at the same place in virtual memory of the process as before?

Comment: @thebigone: You couldn't, hence the problem. @wg32: Okay, if you want everything you write to break every new version of Windows that gets released, be my guest. Until then, I'm going to stick with the supported interfaces, and will not be recommending anyone do otherwise.

Comment: @thebigone: No, because you would have to copy out the memory contents and put them back. You would then have to deal with different region sizes and types (e.g. mapped). It's theoretically possible, but I don't think you want to go there. @Billy ONeal: These interfaces haven't changed since the initial release of Windows NT. Too many people try to avoid learning about Windows internals, repeating the crap on MSDN about it being undocumented and "subject to change". Windows is closed source. It's a fact of life.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. Here's some stuff that might be interesting to you...

For starters, you can't deallocate some other process's memory, nor write it out to disk. Basically you can't see our touch or do anything with another process's memory. But let's say you did, somehow, and now you want to restore it... you're concerned that you can't reallocate it in the same place it was before, so how do find out where you can allocate it and how do you tell the process where it is now. The answer is that you don't need to - you can allocate it anywhere you want, even if another process is already using that address. (Bearing in mind that this is all hypothetical, because you can't even start to do what you want.)

Each process has access to the full range of memory, let's say from zero to 4GB. (We're not interested in details here.) Process A can allocate memory at 0x0, and so can Process B. Each process thinks it's got memory at 0x0, but they don't really.

A process doesn't see physical memory addresses. It sees a "virtual memory address space". The operating system, supported by the hardware, maintains a table that maps physical memory addresses to virtual addresses. There is one such table for each process. When Process A allocates its first byte, the operating system might allocate that byte at 0x1000 in physical memory and then write an entry in Process A's page table to say "virtual 0x0000 = physical 0x1000". From now on, whenever Process A refers to address 0x0000, the hardware (not the operating system) looks up 0x0000 in the table and finds that it really means 0x1000, and reads/writes at 0x1000. When Process B allocates its first byte, the operating system might allocate it at physical address 0x2000, but virtual address 0x0000 in B's page table. That's how two processes can use the same address, simultaneously.

(Obviously I've left out a lot of detail, including user-mode memory managers.)

And so, to your question. If you somehow had deallocated all B's memory and now wanted to restore it, you could restore it to exactly where it was before (in B's virtual address space.) It would probably be somewhere different in physical memory, but you wouldn't need to know or care about that and you wouldn't need to tell Process B about it.

Comment: Wow, nice explanation. So it isn't possible. Thats what I thought but I wasn't sure. What about Read/WriteProcessMemory? What is it supposed to do if you can't read memory out of another process' virtual memory? And what about the pointer in free(void* ptr)? Does it refer only to my virtual table?

Comment: The pointer in free does only refers to your process's virtual addresses.  Any function that refers to an other process's virtual memory would have to take a process handle so it knows what process the address refers to.

Comment: yeah right. That sounds logical to me. So there is nothing like FreeProcessMemory? In this case there is no way of doing what I wanted to do before I did it another way.

Comment: Yes, with Read/WriteProcessMemory you can read and write to another process's memory... provided you can get a handle to the other process with appropriate privileges. Typically these functions are used by a debugger, so that you can read/write variables and so on. But in normal day-to-day situations one process can't call Read/WriteProcessMemory on another process's memory.